# How to remove specific characters from an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, dictionary

I have this array:

```
["House Dad", "House Dog", "House Wife"]
```

I want to find the equivalent of `replacingOccurrences(of: " Dad", with: "")` so that I get:

```
["House", "House Dog", "House Wife"]
```

I also want to remove  `Dog` and  `Wife` so that the final result is:

```
["House", "House", "House"]
```

Is it possible to do that in Swift? Thanks

Comment: Please provide real code... those arrays are invalid because you forgot all the quotes around the strings.

Comment: You are supposed to provide your own attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a solution that would solve your problem for a single string. Now it's just a matter of repeating it for every element. The natural approach would be to use a loop to build up a new array of transformed elements:

```swift
let inputs = ["House Dad", "House Dog", "House Wife"]

var transformedStrings = [String]()

for input in inputs {
    let transformedString = input
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " Dog", with: "") // Not the most efficient...
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " Dad", with: "") // ...but it's a good first start
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " Wife", with: "")
    
    transformedStrings.append(transformedString)
}
```

This pattern is so common, that it's been extracted an given a name in the standard library. So instead of repeating that kind of code every time you need it, you would just use [`Array.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/map(_:)-87c4d), like so:

```swift
let inputs = ["House Dad", "House Dog", "House Wife"]

let transformedStrings = inputs.map { input in
    input
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " Dog", with: "") // Not the most efficient...
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " Dad", with: "") // ...but it's a good first start
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " Wife", with: "")
}
```